# Adding source URI for python3-lxml build-dep

Tags: debian, lxml, apt, debian-stretch

I am trying to run the following command: `apt-get build-dep python3-lxml`.

I get the following output: `E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

Here is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free

#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free
##deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free

#Kernel source (repos.rcn-ee.com) : https://github.com/RobertCNelson/linux-stable-rcn-ee
#
#git clone https://github.com/RobertCNelson/linux-stable-rcn-ee
#cd ./linux-stable-rcn-ee
#git checkout `uname -r` -b tmp
#
deb [arch=armhf] http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/ stretch main
#deb-src [arch=armhf] http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/ stretch main
```

A few questions:

1. How should I modify this file to add the source?
2. Do I need to run `apt update` afterwards?
3. How did you know what URI to add?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** You can edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with any text editor. Just open it and uncomment the required lines that starts with `deb-src` (i.e. remove the `#` in front of `deb-src`), save and close it.

**2.** Yes, after that you'll have to run `apt update`.

**3.** The needed urls are already present in you `sources.list` file.

---

Here is the official documentation about [Debian sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#A.2Fetc.2Fapt.2Fsources.list), as well as some specific information about [Archive Types](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Archive_type) (`deb` and `deb-src`).

And here is some additional information about [Debian Repositories](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository#Mirrors).

Comment: Thank you @Joey for the links.  They were useful.  I found uncommenting the 2nd line in the file solved the problem!